# Hindi text to Image - words not appearing properly PHP

Tags: php

I want to display hindi words on an image. Here is the code for it, it is working properly but it does not display "chote E ki matra" correctly. Example "अब हिन्दी" is displayed as : http://prntscr.com/8rj8mq

Also hindi.txt file contains these :
अब हिन्दी
मे टाइप
करना बहुत आसान है

Below php script read one line randomly and put it on image and display it. Can someone help me to correct this....

```
<?php

$word= file("hindi.txt");
$random = rand(0,2);
$text = $word[$random];

header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw

// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'Mangal.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);


?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sorry but i didnt understand, can you make an example code for it?

Comment: I think the problem is not with font or space. Because instead of displaying this http://prntscr.com/8rn23k This is displayed http://prntscr.com/8rj8mq  . Problem is with the letters of font which are mixed together http://prntscr.com/8rn2ma . I researched more and many fonts but it is problem with free type library...

Comment: Glad you found the source of the problem.

Comment: Maybe I found out the source of the problem but still i don't know how to solve it :D . Anyways thanks for your time :)